# Prove that $ \min\{X,Y\}$ and $\mathbb{1}_{\{X \leq Y\}}$ are independent

Tags: probability, independence

Suppose $X\sim\text{Exp}(\lambda_1)$ and $Y\sim \text{Exp}(\lambda_2)$ are independent. Define $Z := \min\{X,Y\}$ and $S:= \mathbb{1}_{\{X \leq Y\}}$.

I want to prove that $Z$ and $S$ are independent.

I have computed that $Z \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2) $ and we can note that $S\sim \text{Bern}(P(X \leq Y)) $. However I am not sure that this helps me. From the definition of independence we would need to prove that
$$
P(Z \in A, S=s) = P(Z \in A)P(S=s).
$$
Ideally we want to split this into where $S=0$ and $S=1$, and then use that $Z=Y$ and $Z=X$ respectively. However I have hard time making this split and I have tried looking at both the law of total probability and Bayes' formula.

Can anyone help me? If such a question has already been posted on here, feel free to link this - but I could not find it through the search engine.

Answer (score 0):

To give a partial answer to this interesting example, the uncorrelatedness of $Z$ and $S$ is shown quite easily: It is straightforward to check that
\begin{align}
E[Z]&=E\Big[\min\{X,Y\}\Big]=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\min\{x,y\}\lambda_1\lambda_2e^{-\lambda_1x-\lambda_2y}\,dx\,dy
=\frac{1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}\,, \\[3mm]
E[S]&=P[X\le Y]=\int_0^\infty\int_0^y\lambda_1\lambda_2\,e^{-\lambda_1x-\lambda_2y}\,dx\,dy
=1-\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2} \,,\\[3mm]
E[ZS]&=E\Big[\min\{X,Y\}1_{\{X\le Y\}}\Big]=E\Big[X\,1_{\{X\le Y\}}\Big]=\int_0^\infty\int_0^y\lambda_1\lambda_2\,x\,e^{-\lambda_1x-\lambda_2y}\,dx\,dy\\
&=\frac{1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}-\frac{\lambda_2}{(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)^2}\,
\end{align}
hold. Therefore, $E[ZS]=E[Z]E[S]$ by which $Z$ and $S$ are uncorrelated.